# How get charCode from unicode characters?

Tags: javascript, unicode, terminology

I want get charcode from `⌘` (command) and `⌥` (alt) and after convert to something like `\uXXXXX`.

I tried this:

```js
console.log("⌘".charCodeAt(0));
console.log("⌥".charCodeAt(0));
```

And return this:

> 8984
>
> 8997

After I tried:

```js
console.log("\u8984");
console.log("\u8997");

console.log("\uD8984");
console.log("\uD8997");
```

But not work, returns:

> 覄
>
> 覗
>
> �4
>
> �7

- How I get **"escape sequences"** (`\uXXXX` or `\x0000`) from unicode characters?
- What is the correct term to refer to `\uXXXX` and `\x0000`?

Comment: Isn't `\u` hexadecimal and `codePointAt`/`charCodeAt` decimal? :)

Comment: @bzlm Thanks, if I knew the correct term would not have made this mistake, which is the correct term for the `\uXXXX` and `\x0000`?

Comment: I've answered you in a proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `toString(16)` to convert the number to hexadecimal. Then you can convert back using that Unicode codepoint escape sequence.

```js
console.log("⌘".charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
console.log("⌥".charCodeAt(0).toString(16));

console.log("\u2318");
console.log("\u2325");
```

Comment: Should be `.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4,"0")`

Answer (score 2):

the `\uxxxx` uses hexadecimal, charCodeAt is decimal

Comment: An example? And What is the correct term to refer to `\uXXXX` and `\x0000`?

Comment: mozilla seems to call them ["Unicode escape sequences"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#String_literals)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the character codes in hex format:

```js
console.log("⌘".charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
console.log("⌥".charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
```

Comment: What is the correct term to refer to `\uXXXX` and `\x0000`?

Comment: They are called _escape sequences_. \x?? only takes two hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts you need to understand here; decimal numbers (8984) versus hexadecimal numbers (20ac), and the escape sequence used to express Unicode characters inside strings (`\uxxxx`).

`"⌘".charCodeAt(0)` (i.e. 8984) returns the *decimal Unicode code point number* of ⌘.

To express Unicode characters inside strings using their code point numbers, you use the *Unicode string escape sequence* which consists of the *Unicode escape character* `\u` and the *hexadecimal Unicode code point number* `20ac`, i.e. `"\u20ac"`.

You can also use `String.fromCharCode()` with the *decimal Unicode code point number* (i.e. 8984) to get the character, but not inline inside a string.

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(8984));
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, but I want **"escaped sequences"**.

Comment: Oh!The \uxxxx character is used to find the Unicode character specified by a hexadecimal number xxxx. So you can convert to hex then use Unicode escape sequences.

Answer (score -2):

```
console.log("⌘".charCodeAt(0));
console.log("⌥".charCodeAt(0));
```

In decimal format you can find this in following way

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode(8984));
console.log(String.fromCharCode(8997));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want **"escaped sequences"**.

Comment: then you can use parseInt(string,16) or toString(16) function